# Combinations Of Dividing Money

Tags: combinatorics

There is amount of 20000 dollars that needed to be divided into 4 saving programs.
Each investment unit is 1000, and the 4 saving programs are of 2000,2000,3000,4000.

a. How many ways there are to invest the money if you must invest in all the 4?

b. How many ways here are to invest the money if you must invest at least at 3?

Ad for a. it is to find the ways to solve the following $4x_1+3x_2+2x_3+2x_4=20$
so if I must invest in all 4 so it is to invest in each one so is sum up to $4x_1+3x_2+2x_3+2x_4=9$ but what should I do now? as it is not like solving $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=9$?

As for b. I do not have a clue

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: edited, sorry.
there are 20000 dollars thats need to be invested in 4 programs, one of 2000, second 2000, third 3000 and fourth 4000. and you can invest in multiples of 1000

Answer (score 1):

As gbox has explained, we are looking for the number of solutions $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ of $4x_1+3x_2+2x_3+2x_4=9$, with $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\ge 0$ (this is equivalent to looking at the number of solutions of $4x_1+3x_2+2x_3+2x_4=20$, with $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\ge 1$).

For (a), you can just enumerate the possibilities:

$$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(1,1,0,1),(1,1,1,0),(0,3,0,0),(0,1,3,0),(0,1,0,3),(0,1,1,2),(0,1,2,1)$$

So there are $7$ possibilities.

Comment: the answer for a. is 220

Comment: $220$ ways to write $4x_1+3x_2+2x_3+2x_4=9$? Where $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\ge 0$?

Comment: yes I think it is just $9+3 \choose 3$, but it is a bit weird as they are not the same

Comment: Can you indicate one solution that is not among my $7$ above?

Comment: I do not know they 220 is the correct answer

Comment: But $220$ is not the number of solutions to $4x_1+3x_2+2x_3+2x_4=9$. It is the number of solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=9$.

Comment: And there are strictly fewer solutions to the former equation than to the latter ...

Comment: The question states that you must invest in all four savings plans.  The correct answer is 7 but the possibilities posted by user 144248 do not make sense to me.

Comment: His text book errs because $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{9+3}{3}$ is the number of solutions to $x_1+\cdots+x_k=n$ ($x_1+\cdots+x_4=9$) whereas the equation $4x_1+3x_2+2x_3+2x_4=9$ has much fewer solutions than $220$. The correct answer is $7$. It is a pity he trusts his text book more than us.

Comment: But $x_i = 0$ would mean that you're not investing in program $i$?

Comment: @200_success He already subtracted $1$ from each program - the original equation was $4x_1+3x_2+2x_3+2x_4=20$, with $x_i\ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

For question a I have:

`nn = 20; CoefficientList[
 Series[x^11/(1 - x^2)^2/(1 - x^3)/(1 - x^4), {x, 0, nn}], x]`

which returns

`{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 4, 2, 7, 4, 11, 7}`

So the answer is 7.

Here are the 7 ways:

`Select[Compositions[20, 4], 
 FreeQ[#, 0] && Mod[#[[1]], 2] == 0 && Mod[#[[2]], 2] == 0 && 
   Mod[#[[3]], 3] == 0 && Mod[#[[4]], 4] == 0 &]`

which returns:

`{{2, 2, 12, 4}, {2, 4, 6, 8}, {2, 8, 6, 4}, {4, 2, 6, 8}, {4, 6, 6, 
  4}, {6, 4, 6, 4}, {8, 2, 6, 4}}`

For question b I have:

`nn = 20; CoefficientList[
 Series[x^11/(1 - x^2)^2/(1 - x^3)/(1 - x^4) + 
   x^9/(1 - x^2)/(1 - x^3)/(1 - x^4) + 
   x^9/(1 - x^2)/(1 - x^3)/(1 - x^4) + x^8/(1 - x^2)^2/(1 - x^4) + 
   x^7/(1 - x^2)^2/(1 - x^3), {x, 0, nn}], x]`

which returns:

`{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 3, 6, 8, 11, 12, 17, 20, 24, 29, 33,
40}`

So the answer is 40.

Here are 33 of the 40 ways.  To these we would also have the 7 ways from question a:

`Select[Compositions[20, 4], 
 Count[#, 0] == 1 && Mod[#[[1]], 2] == 0 && Mod[#[[2]], 2] == 0 && 
   Mod[#[[3]], 3] == 0 && Mod[#[[4]], 4] == 0 &]`

which returns:

`{{0, 2, 6, 12}, {0, 4, 12, 4}, {0, 6, 6, 8}, {0, 10, 6, 4}, {2, 0, 6, 
  12}, {2, 2, 0, 16}, {2, 6, 0, 12}, {2, 6, 12, 0}, {2, 10, 0, 8}, {2,
   12, 6, 0}, {2, 14, 0, 4}, {4, 0, 12, 4}, {4, 4, 0, 12}, {4, 4, 12, 
  0}, {4, 8, 0, 8}, {4, 10, 6, 0}, {4, 12, 0, 4}, {6, 0, 6, 8}, {6, 2,
   0, 12}, {6, 2, 12, 0}, {6, 6, 0, 8}, {6, 8, 6, 0}, {6, 10, 0, 
  4}, {8, 4, 0, 8}, {8, 6, 6, 0}, {8, 8, 0, 4}, {10, 0, 6, 4}, {10, 2,
   0, 8}, {10, 4, 6, 0}, {10, 6, 0, 4}, {12, 2, 6, 0}, {12, 4, 0, 
  4}, {14, 2, 0, 4}}`

[Editor's note: the above is mostly Wolfram Mathematica inputs and outputs.]